# Not able to build Android gradle project from command line with dagger 2 dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2, annotation-processing

I've bee using dagger for a while and now I'm facing a problem related to the generation of DaggerAppComponent class.

It is working as expected while running the project from Android Studio, but whenever I run the task assembleDebug on command line on the root dir, gradle cannot build the entire project since dagger classes are not being generated.

I am missing some task in order to completly execute the dagger annontation processor?

**Dependencies:**

```
final DAGGER_VERSION = '2.0.1'

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

**This is the final error:**

```
import com.company.injection.DaggerAppComponent;
                           ^
  symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
  location: package com.company.injection
:mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.filterKeys(Lcom/google/common/collect/SetMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Predicate;)Lcom/google/co
mmon/collect/SetMultimap;
```

Just to make sure, the graph is ok and it is working correctly, the problem just happen if I try to build the project by command line with assembleDebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this, I fixed the problem adding the guava dependency as the annotationProcessor **just above** the dagger-compiler.

```
final DAGGER_VERSION = '2.0.1'

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
annotationProcessor 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same config with `'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'` but I was having the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.filterKeys(Lcom/google/common/collect/SetMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Predicate;)Lcom/google/common/collect/SetMultimap;
```

I tried to update the guava version to the current at the time `'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'` but the error continued.

I changed to `'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'` and it worked nicely. May be an incompatibility with others versions.